# Global char *array being overwritten

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to use a globally declared `char *` array in C to store a few names, however, after successfully writing the correct value the whole array gets overwritten with the last value inputted.
I want to be able to store `char` arrays from `stdin` into `char *names[]`, everything seems fine when I run `readNames` function, but if I run `printNames` I notice every space on the array has been overwritten with the last value, why?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUM_OF_NAMES 20
#define NAME_SIZE 15

int readNames(int);
int readName(int);
int sortNames();
int printNames();

char* names[NUM_OF_NAMES];
char nameHolder[NAME_SIZE];

int main () {
    readNames(NUM_OF_NAMES);
    printf("\n");
    printNames();
    return 0;
}

int readNames(int qty) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < qty; i++ ) {
        readName(i);
        printf("%s \n", names[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

int readName() {
    char c;
    for ( int i = 0; i < NAME_SIZE; i++ )
        nameHolder[i] = '\0';
    for ( int i = 0; i < NAME_SIZE; i++ ) {
        c = getchar();
        if ( (c == '\"') || (c == 32) )
            c = getchar();
        if (c == ','){
            names[target] = nameHolder;
            return 0;
        }
        nameHolder[i] = c;
    }
    names[target] = nameHolder;
    return 0;
}

int sortNames() {
    return 0;
}

int printNames() {
    for ( int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_NAMES; i++ ) {
        printf("%s \n", names[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
MARY  PATRICIA  LINDA  BARBARA  ELIZABETH  JENNIFER 
MARIA  SUSAN  MARGARET  DOROTHY  LISA  NANCY  KAREN  BETTY  HELEN 
SANDRA  DONNA  CAROL  RUTH  SHARON 

SHARON  SHARON  SHARON  SHARON  SHARON  SHARON  SHARON  SHARON  SHARON
SHARON  SHARON  SHARON  SHARON  SHARON  SHARON  SHARON  SHARON  SHARON
SHARON  SHARON
```

I tried initializing the `char *` array by writing `15` characters on every element but the results were the same, not sure what's going on here, is there anything else I could try? Preferably without using additional libraries?

Comment: Maybe it is because you assign the same value to each array element with this line `names[target]=nameHolder`

Comment: For Pete's sake read compiler warnings and act on them.

Comment: For pete's sake, no warnings compiling, code is working fine always go with gcc -Wall -Werror -O, go ahead try it, and while you're at it try being helpful every other comment

Comment: Maybe some code that you have is warning free, but then you should probably show it in your question. What you have posted [doesn't even compile](https://ideone.com/IrI9bW). I apologise for misclassifying these errors as warnings before trying to actually compile the code.

Comment: yep, my bad, guess that happens every once in a while, line 21 should not be *
int readName() { *
but should contain (int target) as a parameter...
but that was easy to spot, i do apologize for providing faulty code, still no excuse for acting against all that this community is here for... anyway, i guess this is one of the caveats of working with people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess you are trying to learn C by doing a small program?

First, you should (and I wont be the only one to tell you that) avoid globals. They are a serious security issue and generally show bad coding techniques. There can be situation where you can't avoid some globals, but they are rare and this is not one of them.

You should also consider using a header file (.h) to have your declaration (no obligation, just standard).

Considering your problem :

You have a buffer where you store your getted chars (as names). When you've red all the chars of a name, you assign the array of that buffer to your array of pointers.
But since there is only 1 buffer. You are assigning the exact same buffer address to each of your names array.
Therefore, when you are reading the array of pointer, you are reading 20 times the same pointer (namely, your buffer).

In order to obtain what you desire, you need to have memory to copy your buffer to.
Either by creating an array of array `names[NUM_OF_NAMES][NAME_SIZE]` or by dynamically allocating memory to every word you get.

As for your program, you should consider using the mighty beautiful libraries of C that will allow you to do the kind of stuff you are trying to achieve in a couple of lines.

Comment: thank you very much, I understand now, an array of pointers will only save the address to be referred then, so simple, thanks for the advice, i think every other experienced programmer saw it, but I do appreciate the advice as well

Answer (score 0):

You declare two objects here:

```
char* names[NUM_OF_NAMES];
char nameHolder[NAME_SIZE];
```

The first is an array of pointers, the second is an array of characters.

Your code always writes to this second array, and then sets one of the pointers in the first array to point to the second array. So in the end, all the pointers point to the same object `nameHolder`.

A simple fix would be using a 2D-array instead like this:

```
char names[NUM_OF_NAMES][NAME_SIZE];
```

and then write to `names[i]` (or something like `names[i][j]` if you write individual characters) directly when reading something.

You could also allocate each name separately with `malloc()`.

Comment: Thank you very much, will look into malloc at some point, for now no messing with the memory allocation.

Comment: It's not messing, it's asking the system for memory to use ;-)

Comment: As such, you are doing memory allocation when you are using variables. It's just a matter of STACK vs HEAP ;-)
Also of giving back memory when you don't need it any more ;-)
(free !!)

Comment: @PierrePodevin C doesn't know about stack / heap. As far as C is concerned, an object is *allocated* only by `malloc()` and friends.

Comment: Nope! every time you declare a variable (no matter how big), it's stack memory. Every time you `malloc()`, it's heap.

Comment: @PierrePodevin you didn't understand my comment. Please read a language standard document (or [a draft of it](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html)). And btw, an *implementation* of C doesn't use the *stack* for objects with *static storage duratuion*.

Comment: Ok, let's say it's compiler and kernel problems if you prefer ^^